# Is it possible to write to OpenGL texture 4 different planes

Tags: c, opengl

I'm trying to write data to different planes to opengl texture, is it possible?

I tried following code

```c
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1, 1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)&pixel);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, GL_GREEN, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)&pixel);
```

It doesn't work as I expected, triangle is green instead of yellow, pixel value is 255.

Comment: GL_GREEN and GL_BLUE is valid format. If i use GL_GREEN triangle is green, GL_BLUE, triangle is blue

Comment: I can close question, textures in OpenGL must be stored in linear format, because it's fast format for shader operations. It's not possible to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. The missing channels are "filled" with 0.0 for red, green and blue, respectively 1.0 for the alpha channel.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 8.4.4.4 Final Expansion to RGBA](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=225&zoom=100,168,488):

> [...] Each group is converted to a group of 4 elements as follows: if a group does not contain an A element, then A is added and set to one for integer components or 1.0 for floating-point components. If any of R, G, or B is missing from the group, each missing element is added and assigned a value of 0 for integer components or 0.0 for floating-point components.

Comment: but when i use GL_GREEN texture is green

Comment: @NocturnalCoder007: Yes. Because if you set a color to (0, X, 0, 1), then unless X is zero, the result will be some shade of green. The point is that you're not uploading to a single channel. You're writing to *all channels*; it's just some channels get filled in with data you didn't provide.